# Is it true that $\displaystyle \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \right)^\alpha = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^\alpha $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a squence of nonnegative real numbers such that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =x \in \Bbb R$. If $\alpha \in (0, \infty)$, is it true that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^\alpha =x^\alpha$?

I read the proofs for $\alpha$ integer and for $\alpha=1/2$, but I wonder what happens with the other cases.

Comment: What are the other cases you are thinking of?

Comment: @IAmNoOne Some rational and irrational numbers.

Comment: All numbers $\alpha\in(0,\infty)$ can be written as the sum of some integral part and a fractional part.  Apply the rules separately and there you go.

Comment: Furthermore, your statement is true $\forall\alpha\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @AndrewChin Not all numbers.

Comment: @AndrewChin Ok.

Comment: Yes, all numbers.  A real number $\alpha$ can be written as the sum of $\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+(\alpha-\lfloor\alpha\rfloor)$.

Comment: If you know how to prove it for integers and you know how to prove it for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, then you can prove it for every number $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and more generally for any continuous function $f$, $\displaystyle f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n)=(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n))$

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about that.